# How to create a JDialog ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL in a background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, background, jdialog

I will export data into a XML file and I will show in this time a `JDialog` with the `ModalityType` = `APPLICATION_MODAL`. So the problem is that I can't do my export in an own thread, because I must use a framework for the communication with the database that couldn’t handle multithreading...

So when I override the `setVisible` method to do the export the GUI will not be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: The problem is that I could not do my export in a new Thread because of the framework and SwingWorker would do the background method in a new Thread or?

Comment: with PropertyChangeListener +1

Comment: No it doesn’t work with my framework.. So some ideas are:
I can do the UI update in an own Thread but it had shown no results for me…
Or I can simulate the modal dialog but I do not know how?